# Dos instancias de un plugin jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo definido este plugin de ejemplo,que lo unico que hace es poner el borde rojo y luego mostrar un mensaje con el id:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function () {   
    var nameControl = this.attr('id');
    $(this).css('border','1px solid red')

    $.fn.myPlugin.id = function () {
        alert(nameControl);           
    };

     return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Lo instancio dos veces, con dos txt's diferentes

```
$("#txt1").myPlugin();
$("#txt2").myPlugin();


$("#txt1").myPlugin.id();
$("#txt2").myPlugin.id();
```

Ahora el valor del primero desaparece. El resultado que me devuelve es

```
txt2
txt2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empezaré diciendo que no soy experto en **JQuery** y que nunca había trabajado con la creación de plugins (aviso por si digo alguna burrada o hago las cosas de una manera indevida), pero trasteando con ello he llegado a lo que creo que pretendías alcanzar.

Lo primero de todo es que para tener dos estancias de un mismo objeto, lo que tienes que hacer es almacenarlas en una variable, porque si no vas a tener solamente una instancia a la que vas a acceder múltiples veces, que es lo que te estaba ocurriendo (sobreescribias las variables del objeto y por eso te mostraba solamente las del último elemento).

Luego lo que hice fue capturar el contexto desde el que es lanzado el plugin (en mi caso lo llame **elemento**) y es a este elemento al que le añado atributos o funciones para poder llamarlos a nuestro gusto desde la estancia.

```js
(function (elemento, myFunctionParam, options ) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function () {   
      var elemento = this;
      
      elemento.id = elemento.attr('id');
      elemento.css('border','1px solid red')
      
      elemento.mostrar_id = function () {
        alert(elemento.id);           
      };

      return this;
    };
}(jQuery));

var estancia1 = $("#txt1").myPlugin();
var estancia2 = $("#txt2").myPlugin();

estancia1.mostrar_id();
estancia2.mostrar_id();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="txt1">Hola</p>
<p id="txt2">Adios</p>
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona perfectamente

Comment: Si la respuesta te solucionó el problema haz el favor de aceptarla para que la pregunta quede "cerrada" ^^

Answer (score 0):

id es una propiedad del elemento y estás definiendo un método con dicho nombre

Prueba a cambiar el nombre del método por **theid** por ejemplo:

```
                $.fn.myPlugin.theid = function () {
                    alert(nameControl);           
                };
```